# How to split with multiple delimiters in C

Tags: c, algorithm, split, strsplit

I have this line of text:

```
32+-#3#2-#3#3
```

I need to separate numbers from each other. So basically the result would be like this:

```
3
2+-
3
2-
3
3
```

This is my code but it's not working properly because I have numbers with two digits:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char string[50] = "32-#3#2-#3#3";
    // Extract the first token
    char *token = strtok(string, "#");
    // loop through the string to extract all other tokens
    while (token != NULL) {
        printf(" %s\n", token); //printing each token
        token = strtok(NULL, "#");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Then why don't you just read one character at a time and skip over the delimiter?

Comment: So "32" is not considered "thirty two"? Then I would phrase as "digit" instead of "number".

Comment: *"This is my code but it's not working properly because I have numbers with two digits"* We can't guess what "not working properly" means. Could you at least specify an example input, and the resulting output, and explain clearly why the output differs from what you would want? See also: [What do you mean "It doesn't work?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with `strtok` (alone), because there is no delimiter between the numbers you want to split. It's easier without `strtok`, just print what you want printed and add a separator unless a character which belongs to the token follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char string[] = "32+-#3#2-#3#3";
    for (char *token = string; *token; ++token)
        if ('0'<=*token && *token<='9' || *token=='+' || *token=='-')
        {
            putchar(*token);
            if (token[1]!='+' && token[1]!='-') putchar('\n');
        }
}
```

If you consider this too easy, you can use a regular expression to match the tokens:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main()
{
    char *string = "32+-#3#2-#3#3";
    regex_t reg;
    regcomp(&reg, "[0-9][+-]*", 0);
    regmatch_t match = {0};
    while (regexec(&reg, string+=match.rm_eo, 1, &match, 0) == 0)
        printf("%.*s\n", (int)(match.rm_eo-match.rm_so), string+match.rm_so);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to achieve this, but in `C` is a bit more complicated since we don't have `vector` as in `C++` but I can suggest a pure `C` implementation which can be improved:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void split_ss(const char* src,const char* pattern, char** outvec, size_t* outsize)
{
    const size_t  pat_len = strlen(pattern);
    char* begin = (char*) src;
    const char* next = begin;
    if ((begin = strstr((const char*)begin, pattern)) != 0x00) {
        unsigned int size = begin - next;
        *outvec = malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
        memcpy(*outvec , next, size);
        outvec++;
        (*outsize)+=1;
        split_ss(begin+pat_len, pattern, outvec, outsize);
    } else {
        unsigned int size = &src[strlen(src)-1] - next + 1;
        *outvec = malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
        memcpy(*outvec, next, size);
        (*outsize) += 1;
    }
}


int main()
{
    char* outdata[64] = {0};
    size_t size, i=0;
    split_ss("32+-#3#2-#3#3", "#", outdata, &size);
    for(i=0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("[%s]\r\n", outdata[i]);
    }

    // make sure to free it

    return 0;
}
```

`strstr` is used to split by string rather than a character. Also output is a poorman 2D array with out size to iterate it and don't forget to free it.

Answer (score 0):

`strtok()` is not the right tool for you purpose... As a matter of fact `strtok()` is rarely the right tool for any purpose because of its tricky semantics and side effects.

A simple loop will do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char string[50] = "32+-#3#2-#3#3";

    for (char *p = string; *p; p++) {
        if (*p == '#')
            continue;
        putchar(*p);
        while (p[1] == '+' || p[1] == '-')
            putchar(*++p);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```